# Android apps cannot connect to google maps service directly?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I am having a problem downloading directions from google maps from my app. This used to work before, and it still works fine from a browser or even an iOS app that uses the same URL, but it does not work on Android. Is Google blocking connections to maps.google.com from Android devices for some reason? Is there a workaround?

Here is what I tried:

```
    private class RouteRetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    String url;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        url = arg0[0];
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                //Get the Stream reader ready
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()),8192);
                //Loop through the return data and copy it over to the response object to be processed
                String line = null;
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    response.append(line);
                }
                input.close();
                conn.disconnect();
            } else return null;

            return response.toString();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pbloading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (result!=null) {
            tvresult.append(result.substring(0, 100));
        }
        else {
            tvresult.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            tvresult.setText("Download error");
        }
    }

}
```

This works fine if I execute with http://www.google.com but returns null (responsecode returns -1) if I send http://maps.google.com/

Can anyone point me to the right directions on how to fix this?

Thanks so much!

Jit

Comment: Why don't you use the Maps API for android version 2?

Comment: Actually my app uses the route data returned my google maps and does some calculations based on the returned route. I do not think the Maps API provides a way to retrieve a route between two points.